# android nested lists

Tags: android, listview, nested-lists

i'm new to programming android and i have found some useful things for my app, but i can't seem to find how to make a list filled with an string array display a new list that is going to be populated with a string array. i would like to have the user choose an item from the `top_menu` list and from there go to the desired area and have that array appear.

this is what i have so far:

```
public class HelloListActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  String[] top_menu = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.top_menu);
  setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, top_menu));

  ListView lv = getListView();
  lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

  lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        ???
    }
  });
}
```

all my arrays are working fine, i just don't know how to repopulate a new list with the other array depending on the choice the user made.

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: use Expandable ListView and try..

Comment: i will definitely give that a try, but will it be able to open a new form so that it doesn't get too cluttered on one page?

Answer (score 1):

You can setlistAdaptor again in `onItemClick()` block.

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        System.out.println("item clicked: "+top_menu[position]);
    }
  });
```

Comment: so i would pretty much be doing this:
    `lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
R.layout.list_item, new_array));
    }`

but from that how would i be able to detect how which item they chose?

Comment: see my updated answer you will get to know which item is selected.

Comment: it gives an error saying you can't use get(int) on an array type of string, would it be possible to do it in another way?

Comment: it should be `top_menu[position]` not `top_menu.[position]`

Comment: now how would i correlate that to the proper list?
i was thinking maybe some sort of if or case statement.

Comment: ok this is what i got:
`System.out.println("item clicked: "+top_menu[position]);
      switch(position){
      case 1:
       String[] weapons = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weapons);
       setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, weapons));
       break;`

but i'm getting this error `The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, int, String[]) is undefined` on the `setListAdapter` lines

Comment: Instead using this try HelloListActivity.this. 
switch(position){ case 1: String[] weapons = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weapons); setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(HelloListActivity.this, R.layout.list_item, weapons)); break; but i'm getting this error The constructor ArrayAdapter<String>(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, int, String[]) is undefined on the setListAdapter

Comment: thank you very much :D!!!!
its working like a charm. so i would pretty much do something like this for any other nested lists that i would make?